# IBOutlet is nil in IBDesignable class

Tags: swift, nib, custom-view

I have a custom view class that is supposed to just contain a label. I have an extension in each target that will provide the text that should be displayed in the view, this way I don't have recreate each controller just to have a different label and background color in it.

My custom code is:

```
@IBDesignable
class HomeAccentView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.main

        nameLabel.text = String.headerText
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

I have my nib's file owner as `HomeAccentView` and the label is connected as an outlet on the storyboard.[image: nib storyboard]

But whenever I try to set the text of the label it's always nil. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You did not set class for view. You set only file owner, which means that you told that HomeAccessView is responsible for loading the view, but your code is not showing this. Is there any motive behind this? Otherwise, remove class from file owner and set it for view.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking. The screenshot is the nib that has the components that will load into the controller I put this in. I have a controller on my main storyboard that has a view whose class is set to `HomeAccentView`. Does that clear things up?

Comment: That's not how nibs work, if you create a view with a nib you have to load it using that nib file, you can't set the class in a view in an unrelated view controller and expect it to use the contents of the nib.

Comment: Just to expand Emilios comment, is this what you are trying to achieve? https://medium.com/@ludovicjamet/how-to-use-storyboard-to-create-and-preview-custom-views-92acad7405fa

Comment: @Luzo to a degree. The example you gave is just a button with no subviews. As far as changing the background color, my class is already doing that.

Comment: @CodyHarness , did you read it properly? Of course, it is not 100% match with your code. It is an an idea, that you should grasp. To be clear, you need to wrap your view in order to be able to reuse it, like they did it in example and load it in the wrapper. Just look up embedding custom view to storyboard, there are tons of articles about it. And about the background color, of course it works, you have an empty view(because you are not loading the view), even that has background color, which can be changed.